# Complex Many to Many Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have to do the following relationship:
[image]

any idea how to implement this relationship with the Eloquent laravel?

I'm having trouble implementing the relationship between "drug", "prescription" and "hour"

Comment: Could you write a usecase?

Comment: image with better quality: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BWK90.jpg

Comment: hope you can help me. Here is the use case http://prntscr.com/5aq6ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the relationship "prescription_drug_has_hour" you have n-ary relationship, exactly 3 tables, you can do this like you do for a normal ManyToMany :

```
relations on Prescription:
belongsToMany('Drug','prescription_drug_has_hour')->withPivot('hour_id');
belongsToMany('Hour','prescription_drug_has_hour')->withPivot('drug_id');
// and so on
```

For the "drug" has active principle it's just a normal ManyToMany (without the `withPivot`)

note that if you want to make more attributes available when you have a relationship that carries attribues you can add them to the withPivot function like so :

```
// prescription_has_drug
// ...
// relation on Prescription:
belongsToMany('Drug','prescription_has_drug')->withPivot('via_id', 'method_id', 'miligram', 'observation');
```

Comment: You welcome @user3745828 , I had the same issue once ;)

Comment: a doubt arise now, and if I wanted to make a record of a prescription with "n" drugs and each with their hour?